# Custom HTML5 attribute in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I have the following div in HTML5:

`<div data-thumbnail="images/TV_Logos/tv1_logo.jpg" ></div>`

How do I present it in Ruby on Rails. I have tried the following, but gave me errors:

`<%= tag ( :div, :data {:thumbnail => (image_tag "TV_Logos/tv1_logo.jpg")}) %>`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for content_tag, you should do this:

```
<%= content_tag(:div, :data => {:thumbnail => (image_tag "TV_Logos/tv1_logo.jpg")}) %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

well, you mistyped. It should look like

```
<%= tag ( :div, data: {:thumbnail => "TV_Logos/tv1_logo.jpg"}) %>
```

or like that

```
<%= tag ( :div, :data => {:thumbnail => "TV_Logos/tv1_logo.jpg"}) %>
```